# The permanent of a doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, induction, permanent

**Question:**

If $A$ is a doubly stochastic matrix(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) of order $n$ whose diagonals entries are all $0$ and each off-diagonal entry is
$1/(n-1)$ then can we find some pattern in permanent of $A$ as it is some special kind of matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this work for $n=4$?

Comment: @Mindlack yes Sir I think so.

Comment: @Mindlack   Yes Sir there is some mistake in my calculations I will correct it, But Is there any pattern or formula of such kind of matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that :

$$ \mbox{perm}(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i = 1}^n A_{i, \sigma(i)} $$

The only $\sigma \in S_n$ such that the product is not $0$ are those such that $\sigma(i) \neq i$ for all $i$. Denote this subset of permutations $D_n \subset S_n$. For $\sigma \in D_n$, the product is always $(n-1)^{-n}$ so it does not depend on $\sigma$. Therefore :

$$ \mbox{perm}(A) = \frac{|D_n|}{(n-1)^n} $$

I don't think there is an explicit formula for $|D_n|$, except the following (not entirely satisfying) :

$$ |D_n| = n! \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} $$

from which you have the asymptotic behaviour :

$$ \mbox{perm}(A) \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} e^{-n} $$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Sir Can you give the proof or I can say how you imagine like in numerator this is $D_n$ in this formula because i also find permanent upto matrix of order 8 i have found pattern in denominator but not in numerator terms I hope you get my doubt  $$ \mbox{perm}(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i = 1}^n A_{i, \sigma(i)} $$

Comment: I am simply counting the $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $\prod_{i = 1}^n A_{i, \sigma(i)} \neq 0$, and there are precisely $|D_n|$. However, as you said, there is no "pattern" for $|D_n|$ (but it can be interpreted as the cardinal of the set $D_n$).

Comment: Okay, Sir Thanks!

Comment: How are we able to prove that $D_n$ can be expressed as in that closed-form??

Comment: You can try to prove first : $|D_{n+2}| = (n+1)(|D_{n+1}| + |D_n|)$ and then try to prove by induction that $|D_n| = n |D_{n-1}| + (-1)^n$. The formula should be easy to prove by induction starting from there.